# does zookeeper C binding work with ipv6 addresses?

Tags: ipv6, apache-zookeeper

does zookeeper C binding work with ipv6 addresses?

i am using zookeeper version

```
3.4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. The configure script can identify if the compilation machine has ipv6 supported or not, and generates test cases for testing ipv6.
the implementation supports it based on if the compilation env has AF_INET6 defined in the headers or not